# Getting an Accurate Transformed Region

Tags: complex, regions

I would like to get an accurate plot of the image of concentric circles under the transformation $$f(z) = \log(1+z).$$

I've defined $\cal R$ as the union of a few circles:

```
p[x_, y_][\[Alpha]_] := x^2 + y^2 - \[Alpha]^2;
m = Table[ImplicitRegion[p[x, y][\[Alpha]] == 0, {x, y}], 
          {\[Alpha], Range[7]/7}];
\[ScriptCapitalR] = RegionUnion[m];
a = Region[\[ScriptCapitalR], BaseStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, .8, .7], 
           Frame -> True];
```

Now the function $f(z)$ is defined in terms of its real and imaginary parts:

```
f = Evaluate[{1/2 Log[(1 + x)^2 + y^2], ArcTan[y/(1 + x)]}] &;


\[ScriptCapitalE] = TransformedRegion[\[ScriptCapitalR], f]; 
b = Region[\[ScriptCapitalE], BaseStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0, .7], 
           Frame -> True];
```

$\cal E$ is the transformed region.  We then plot $a$ and $b$ the regions defined by $\cal R$ and $\cal E$, respectively.

```
GraphicsRow[{a, b}]
```

[image]

My question is this:  All of the red curves look nice with the exception of the outermost one.  This curve should go off to infinity (to the left) as $z \rightarrow -1$ but *Mathematica* wants to connect it.  Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Although the answers in the comments work and are expedient, there still remains a question.  Obviously, we cannot get the solution all the way out to the point at infinity.  Still what if we wanted to plot a solution valid in the region $ x \ge -10$, for example?  How can we improve the accuracy by, for example, specifying more sample points as *Mathematica* does its computations?

Comment: Truncating the plot range on it should work.

Comment: `GraphicsRow[{a, Show[b,PlotRange->{{-5,1},{-2,2}}]}]`

Comment: Yes, this is a concise elegant solution!  Works very well for this case.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method for displaying the correct part of the plot was given in the comments.  Thank you!  The **Update** added to the question asks if we can view more of the correct solution.

```
GraphicsRow[{a, Show[b, PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-2, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

*Here is another, probably more difficult question involving transformed regions in the complex plane:*

[Getting an Accurate Transformed Region (Part II)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203327/getting-an-accurate-transformed-region-part-ii)